# How does Rails correctly test code that uses transactions while wrapping each test case in a transaction?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, transactions

This [warning](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html) (scroll down to "Nested Transactions") points out that the function `foo`:

```
def foo
  User.transaction do
    <stuff that mutates the database>
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
  end
end
```

will behave differently depending on whether it is called from inside a transaction block or not. I know this, and I also know that Rails executes each test case inside a transaction.

I have functions that look like `foo`, and they behave as expected under test. My question is: how does Rails achieve this? Does it monkey-patch `ActiveRecord::Base#transaction` to include `requires_new: true` by default in tests?

(I'm on Postgres.)

Comment: You know what? I'm also curious

Answer (score 1):

Turned out to be simpler than I thought:

```rb
def transaction(requires_new: nil, isolation: nil, joinable: true, &block)
# the big reveal ----------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

*https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.0.4.3/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb#L309*

```rb
def test_me
  transaction joinable: false do   # test transaction
    transaction do                 # your transaction
      Item.create!
      raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
    end
  end
end
# just like a test log
#=>
# TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  begin transaction
# TRANSACTION (0.0ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
# Item Create (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "items" DEFAULT VALUES
# TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT active_record_1
# TRANSACTION (9.7ms)  commit transaction
```

and it's the same as this:

```rb
def test_me
  transaction do
    transaction requires_new: true do
      Item.create!
      raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
    end
  end
end
```

Test transaction starts here:
*https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.0.4.3/activerecord/lib/active_record/test_fixtures.rb#L132*

---

Setup:

```rb
# app/models/item.rb

class Item < ApplicationRecord
  def self.dont_make_item
    transaction do
      Item.create!
      raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
    end
  end

  def self.do_make_item
    transaction do
      transaction do
        Item.create!
        raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
      end
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
# no surprises here
>> Item.dont_make_item
  TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  Item Create (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "items" DEFAULT VALUES
  TRANSACTION (0.2ms)  rollback transaction

# but this one commits the transaction
>> Item.do_make_item
  TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  Item Create (1.3ms)  INSERT INTO "items" DEFAULT VALUES
  TRANSACTION (9.5ms)  commit transaction
```

To get the vocabulary straight here:

```rb
# this is a transaction block
transaction do 
end

# this is the actual database transaction
TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  begin transaction
TRANSACTION (0.2ms)  commit transaction

# notice how nested transaction block...
transaction do 
  transaction do 
  end
end
# ...doesn't make a second database transaction
TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  begin transaction
TRANSACTION (9.5ms)  commit transaction
# the only thing nested transaction block does is catch the error
raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
# but there is no actual database transaction for that block to rollback
# so nothing happens
```

But in a test `dont_make_item` is wrapped in a transaction twice, but still works as expected.

```rb
# test/models/item_test.rb

require "test_helper"

class ItemTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "dont make item" do
    Item.dont_make_item
    assert_equal 0, Item.count
  end
end
```

```rb
  TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  begin transaction
------------------------------
ItemTest: test_dont_make_item
------------------------------
  TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  Item Create (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "items" DEFAULT VALUES
  TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  Item Count (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "items"
  TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
```

`SAVEPOINT active_record_1` is what happens when you specify `requires_new: true` option for a nested transaction block. Except there is no `requires_new:` option on our transaction. Rails magic explained at the top ^.